# Not getting correct values in I2C interfacing in Atmega

Tags: c, embedded, avr, i2c, atmega

I'm very new to the concept of I2C and I've been having some problems interfacing I2C between 2 Atmega32(s).

I have one Atmega32 as a Master to which an LCD screen is connected and another I2C as a slave to which a LM35 has been connected and both of these Atmega have been connected with the SDA and SCL lines.

So, although I am getting data on the LCD screen attached to the master, I'm not getting the right values. Like the temperature is 28 Centigrade here but the LCD that is connected to the master keeps repeating 65280 for some reason. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Code for both the master and slave devices have been posted below.

The Master code:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int xx=0x00;
    unsigned char yy;
    DDRA=0xff;
    I2C_init(); //I2C initialization
    lcd_init(); //LCD initialization
    while(1)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) //Getting unsigned int data from slave, so
        {                     //broke data into 4 parts and receiving 
            if (i==0)         //one byte at a time. 
            {
                I2C_start(0x01);  //I2C start along with the address of the slave
                yy=I2C_read_ack(); //Read slave data along with an acknowledgment 
                xx |= (yy << 8);    
                I2C_stop(); //I2C stop function.
            }
            else if (i>0)
            {
                I2C_start(0x01+1); //don't know any particular reason
                yy=I2C_read_ack(); //behind this, but if i don't do 0x01+1
                xx |= (yy << 8);   //then the master ends up reading the
                I2C_stop();        //address as a data packet.
            }
        }
     lcd_num(xx);   //lcd function to display unsigned int data.
    }
}
```

The Slave code:

The slave code is just repeating one function again and again so I'm not posting the whole code, just the snippets in between.

```
int main(void)
{
unsigned int byte = 1;
unsigned int toTransfer;
unsigned int mask = 0xFF;
unsigned int xx;
unsigned char toSend = 0;
TWI_init_slave(0x01); //initializing slave i2c with address
adc_init(); //initialize adc
while(1)
{
    xx=adc_read(0); //reading from ADC0 of the Atmega.
    toTransfer = (5.0 * xx * 100.0) / 1024; //calibrating the temperature

    if (byte == 1) //send packet 1
    {
        toSend = toTransfer & mask; //sending the first 8 bits of data.
        toTransfer = toTransfer >> 8;//right shift so that the next function will take the 8-16 bits of data.
        TWI_match_write_slave(); //I2C function to verify address
        TWI_write_slave(toSend); //I2C function to write data on to master
        byte = 2;
    }

    /*Repeating this till byte 4*/

    else if (byte == 4) //send packet 4
    {
        toSend = toTransfer & mask;
        toTransfer = toTransfer >> 8;
        TWI_match_write_slave();
        TWI_write_slave(toSend);
        byte = 1;
        //initialization for next turn
        mask = 0xFF;
        toSend = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "... Atmega have been connected with the SDA and SCL lines.". I presume you did add proper pullups (with appropriate voltage level) and did not forget the ground connection.

Comment: yes,  that has been done properly.

Answer (score 0):

In the Master code, `xx` is never set, except when it is declared, it is only modified. So I suggest you initialise `xx` within one of the loops, not sure which, because `lcdnum()` is within the `for` loop.

**EDIT:** there are several things wrong with the receiver loop.

- No initialisation of accumulator
- Wrong loop control (3 instead of 4)
- Incorrect shifting
- Incorrect byte order (l.s. byte was sent first)

I suggest rewriting the code block as

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    if (i==0)                   // if first byte
    {
        I2C_start(0x01);
        xx = I2C_read_ack();    // initialise accumulator with first byte
        I2C_stop();
    }
    else                        // no need to test i again
    {
        I2C_start(0x01+1);
        yy = I2C_read_ack();
        xx |= (yy << (i*8));    // update accumulator
        I2C_stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: that's by mistake, lcd_num is supposed to be outside the for loop, i made a small error while editing the code for the question. i'll try initializing xx inside the loop and check once.
EDIT: I've edited the code for lcd_num to be outside the for loop.

Comment: This is giving the correct values, but i'm getting a lot of junk data in between. Like the temperature's 28 but in the receiver it prints 28 and then 54 and then 28 and then so on.

Comment: You slave code's `main` is incomplete. It does not declare any variables, lacks any loop, and you only initialise `mask` and `byte` at the end - that should be done at the start.

Comment: Did you change the receiver's loop counter as I suggested to 4?

Comment: i have declared those variables in the start. i just haven't posted it.Let me edit the code in the question and i've changed the receiver's loop counter to 4.

Comment: I've noticed that whatever the data i'm receiving on the slave through the adc, the master shows the same thing. Like i put the lm35 on a heated object and I've connected an LCD on the slave as well just to verify the values. So even though the temperatures increasing, I'm getting the same data on the master.